Работа со SQlite в qt
мне нужно сделать работу с локальной базой данных в моем приложении. В функции insertCategoryData у меня добавляются в бд данные с массива vector. При попытке что-то добавить в бд я получаю ошибку Failed to insert data: QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", ""). Из-за чего может возникать такая ошибка?
struct CategoryData {
    int id;
    float amount;
    QDate date;
};
DatabaseManager::DatabaseManager()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("data.db");

    if (!db.open()) {
        qDebug() << "Error: connection with database failed";
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "Database: connection ok";
        QSqlQuery query;
        QString createTableQueryUser = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users ("
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            "username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, "
            "password TEXT NOT NULL)";
        if (!query.exec(createTableQueryUser)) {
            qDebug() << "Unable to create table 'users':" << query.lastError().text();
        }
        QString createTableQueryCategoryData = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CategoryData ("
            "index INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            "amount REAL NOT NULL, "
            "date TEXT NOT NULL)";
        if (!query.exec(createTableQueryCategoryData)) {
            qDebug() << "Unable to create table 'CategoryData':" << query.lastError().text();
        }
    }
}
void DatabaseManager::insertCategoryData(const QVector<CategoryData>& data)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO CategoryData (index, amount, date) "
        "VALUES (:index, :amount, :date)");

    for (auto item : data) {
        query.bindValue(":index", item.id);
        query.bindValue(":amount", item.amount);
        query.bindValue(":date", item.date.toString(Qt::ISODate));

        if (!query.exec()) {
            qDebug() << "Failed to insert data:" << query.lastError();
        }
    }
}
``


Я не вижу ошибок, вроде всё верно. / Предлагаю проверить таблицу CategoryData и убедиться, что в ней действительно имеются три указанных колонки. Потому что CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS не создаст таблицу с тремя колонками, если она уже есть (с меньшим их количеством или с другими названиями).

Спасибо за помощь, дело оказалось в том что для бд нельзя создавать переменную с названием index

SQLite Keywords - список ключевых слов SQLite. Там же описано, как их можно использовать.

Нельзя давать переменой SQLite имя index.

По идее можно, если взять это имя в кавычки
